# why are the set of divisors of the integer $a$ and the set of divisors of the integer $-a$ are the same set

Tags: number-theory

Mathematically why the set of divisors of the integer $a$ and the set of divisors of the integer $-a$ are the same set.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Your question will be better received if you add some context: perhaps you could say why you think the two sets should be different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given two non-zero integers $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, we write $b \mid a$ ($b$ divides $a$) if and only if there exists a $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a=k \times b$. The set of divisors of a can be written as $D_a=\{r \in \mathbb{Z}|r \mid a \} $. Suppose that $b \in D_a$ and thus also that $-b \in D_{-a}$ (this follows trivially by simply multiplying everything by $-1$). Is $-b$ a divisor of $a$? Yes, because $$a=k \times b=k \times (-1) \times (-b)=(-k) \times (-b)$$ Therefore $-b \in D_a$, and given that $b$ was arbitrary, we have $D_{-a} \subseteq D_a$. Now is $b$ a divisor of $-a$? Again, yes, since $$-a=(-1) \times a=(-1) \times (k \times b)=(-k) \times b$$ so $b \in D_{-a}$. Hence we also have $D_a \subseteq D_{-a}$, and thus $D_a=D_{-a}$.

Let's do an example. The number $12$ has a set of divisors $D_{12}=\{\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 3,\pm 4,\pm 6,\pm 12\}$ which has 12 elements in total (counting both positive and negative divisors). For instance, $4 \mid 12$, and so $12=4 \times k$, in this case $k=3$. Then clearly $-4 \mid 12$ when we take $k=-3$. An identical argument applies for $-12$.

Comment: I'm writing this comment here, because you proposed a modification of my answer. "integer" is a noun, "integral" is an adjective. It was proper use.

Comment: @enedil It's not very common to use in this context, but do as you like!

Answer (score -1):

If $d$ divides $a$ then $d$ divides $-a$ and conversely, if $d$ divides $-a$ then $d$ divides $a$. Thus the sets of divisors are the same.

A little explanation:

Suppose $d$ divides $a$. Then for some $k$, $a = dk$. Then $-a = -dk = d\cdot(-k)$. Thus $d$ divides $a$ (because $-k$ is integral for integral $k$).